# php5 static properties

Tags: php, oop, static

Is it possible to get property default value in static context an property value in non-static context?

```
class A{

$property = 1;

static function test(){
    echo $this->property;
}

function test1(){
    echo $this->property;
}
}

$v = new A();
A::test();
A::test1()
```

;

outputs 11

Comment: I'm surprised PHP lets you refer to `$this` from a static method. That makes no sense. Silly language.

Comment: It generates an E_STRICT warning, but those are by default turned off in php.ini.

Comment: I'm asking is this the correct way to do things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static function test(){
    echo $this->property;
}
```

This is not the correct way to use $this. You should not use $this in static function, or any function which is is statically called.

You will get unwanted result from this.

In functions which are statically called, $this will not be the object of Same Class.

Edit :

To get default value you can use

```
class A{

static $property = 1;

static function test(){
    echo self::$property;
}

function test1(){
    echo self::$property;  // or you can use class name instead of self
}
}
```

Comment: in most cases, it actually works. Of course, this is NOT the right approach. Another silly behaviour of PHP...

Comment: But how to get the default value in static context? How to do this elegant?